# How to configure PAgP or LACP on GNS3

Tags: etherchannel, gns3, ieee-802.1ax

In gns3, when i configure a router with a NM-16ESW module to use as a switch. And I can not configure PAgP or LACP on this router. It has only one mode ON, and there is no DESIRABLE or AUTO or ACTIVE or PASSIVE mode. 
Can you show me help me to do this ? 
I saw in this video: http://gns3vault.com/Switching/pagp-lacp-etherchannel.html
he did it very easy with no problem.
Thanks you.

Comment: In the [GNS3 Vault lab link](http://gns3vault.com/Switching/pagp-lacp-etherchannel.html) that you included in your question, one of the first things that they state is, quote: **For this lab you need REAL hardware. You can't use switches in GNS3!**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need real switches since there is no emulator for their ASICs. GNS3 can emulate only routers (and run their IOS images). You can try Cisco Packet Tracer for switches, but keep in mind that it is a simulator and it does not have full set of features you will find on real equipment.

Answer (score 2):

Even in real hardware, the HWIC-4ESW and 16ESW modules do NOT support LACP/PAgP

In order to play with these sorts of tech you'll need a regular Cisco switch that support it or another vendor of course

Answer (score 0):

Please find latest updates on GNS3.
It now supports etherchannel, spanning tree features and other L2 features as well.
http://docs.gns3.com/1aQSkL4KyIh-3j-UCeuukj4Wg1VJ7uI-vwcewaUHbjbU/